# Show that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\int_X|gf_k|d\mu<+\infty$ implies $|g|\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|f_k|<+\infty$ almost everywhere on X.

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

The problem arises from Walter Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*:
[image]

**My Background**: Rudin's PMA Chapter 1-7.

**My Question: How does "(103) almost everywhere on X" follow from (102)?**

**My Attempt**: By Theorem 11.30, we may interchange the summation and integration in (102): $\int_X\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|g(f_{n_k}-f_{n_k+1})|d\mu\leq\lVert g\rVert<+\infty$, which "seems" to imply $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|g(f_{n_k}-f_{n_k+1})|<+\infty$ almost everywhere on $X$.

Claim: $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|g(f_{n_k}-f_{n_k+1})|<+\infty$ almost everywhere on $X$.    $(*)$

Proof: Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that for all measurable $A\subset X$, either $\mu(A)\neq0$ or $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|g(f_{n_k}-f_{n_k+1})|=+\infty$ for some $x\in X-A$. Note $\mu(\emptyset)=0$, thus there is some $x\in X-\emptyset=X$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|g(f_{n_k}-f_{n_k+1})|=+\infty$. Let $E=\{x\in X|\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|g(f_{n_k}-f_{n_k+1})|=+\infty\}$. I wish to show that $\mu(E)\neq0$, because then we'd have $\int_E \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|g(f_{n_k}-f_{n_k+1})|d\mu=+\infty$, which would imply that $\int_X \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|g(f_{n_k}-f_{n_k+1})|d\mu=+\infty$. But how? I'm not even sure that if $E$ is measurable. **Screeching halt**.

Then I realized that even IF I proved $(*)$, it still does not lead us to "$|g|\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|f_{n_k}-f_{n_k+1}|<+{\infty}$ almost everywhere".

Any hint would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suggest getting rid of the clutter and proving that if $\phi:X\to [0,\infty]$ is measurable, and $\int_X\phi\,d\mu<\infty$, then $\phi$ is finite a.e (the contrapositive probably sounds much more obvious).

Comment: "I'm not even sure that if E is measurable." -- It is.  Specifically, continuous functions of measurable functions are measurable and pointwise limits of sequences of measurable functions are measurable.  Use those to show $E$ is measurable.

Comment: "Then I realized that even IF I proved $(*)$, it still does not lead us to '$|g|\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|f_{n_k}-f_{n_k+1}|<+{\infty}$ almost everywhere' " -- Why do you think it doesn't lead directly to what you want?  Are you mistakenly interpreting $g(f_{n_k} - f_{n_{k+1}})$ as composition instead of mutliplication?

Comment: That sure is a nice tip-much appreciated! The reason I said that is because that we have $|g(f_{n_k}-f_{n_k+1})|\leq|g||f_{n_k}-f_{n_k+1}|$, not $|g(f_{n_k}-f_{n_k+1})|\geq|g||f_{n_k}-f_{n_k+1}|$; thus $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|g(f_{n_k}-f_{n_k+1})|<+\infty$ does not seem to give $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|g||f_{n_k}-f_{n_k+1}|<+\infty$.

Comment: I don't know why you think that.  If you have two numbers $a,b$, then $|ab| = |a| |b|$.  The same applies to the absolute value of the product of functions.  --------  It occurs to me that you may be mistaking $|f|$, which is defined by $|f|(x) = |f(x)|$, with $\|f\| = \sqrt{\int_X |f|^2\,d\mu}.$  They aren't the same.

Comment: @BrianMoehring $|ab|=|a||b|$ does hold when both $a, b\in\mathbb{R}$; but when $a, b\in\mathbb{C}$, that does not necessarily hold any more.

Comment: @DickGrayson No.  [You're just wrong](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Complex_Modulus_of_Product_of_Complex_Numbers), and I don't even have a guess where your mistake lies anymore.

Comment: @BrianMoehring I am beyond embarrassed. Thank you so much for putting up with me Brain!